# git: list of files with corresponding revision of last change

Tags: git, list, file, hash, revision

Is it possible to get a list of files with corresponding revision of last change from remote?
For example I could execute

`git ls-files`

or

`git diff --name-only origin/master..HEAD`

and then havind the list of the files I could do

`git log origin/master -n 1 --pretty=format:%h -- fileName`

for each.
But I would love to do it in the most elegant way. Preferably using only git commands.
The ideal output would look like this:

```
file1 35acf7e2f89502f7fd5868732788d9c72349165f
file2 2aa721537dd3ba64967c2b00441cebb8775ded74
file3 c4e0c00181e23f03c128588620f5270a360de03b
file4 35588dd34113e9f9a843d987774d173fb63b5409
...
```

or first revision, then file name.

Answer (score 1):

```
git ls-files | while read file; \
    do \
        git log -n 1 --pretty="%h $file" -- $file; \
    done
```

`ls-files` will list the files in the working tree, which could then be piped to git log for every file to get the commit.

```
git ls-files | xargs -n 1 -I {} \
    sh -c 'git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%h -- {} ; echo " {}"'
```

The same using xargs